# redirect_to using PATCH verb not GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller

I am in the process of migrating some of my requests in my rails 4 app to ajax and am having a bit of trouble with a redirect.

On the home page I have a list of items that can be enabled/disabled, easy enough. This is all taken care with one of two links `<%= link_to "disable", toggle_my_class_path(my_class), method: "PATCH", remote: true %>`

In the `ApplicationController` I have a `before_action` that checks if the current user is logged and if not redirects them to the homepage where the log in form is displayed.

```
def require_login
  unless current_user
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Please log in"
  end
end
```

The issue is that (I think) because of the ajax call somehow the PATCH verb is being used instead of GET which is causing a route problem. Below is my log output from the call

```
Started PATCH "/my_class/2/toggle" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-10 16:33:52 -0500
Processing by MyClassController#toggle as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)


Started PATCH "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-10 16:33:56 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/"):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

You can see that **ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/"):** is the issue

I'm not sure of a way around this. I don't want the `PATCH` verb to be used however I can't seem to find a way to specify the verb in `redirect_to`

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can't redirect from server side (controller) within an `ajax` call. Everything retrieved via javascript returns to javacript. So you need to perform that redirect using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redirect from server side (controller) within an ajax call. Everything retrieved via javascript returns to javacript; the web browser is expecting some javascript to be evaluated.

So you need to perform that redirect using javascript.

For example, you can change the `before_action` (code not tested):

```
def require_login
  unless current_user
    if request.xhr?
      flash[:notice] = "Please log in"
      flash.keep(:notice) # Keep flash notice for the redirect
      render js: "window.location = #{root_url.to_json}" # js to be evaluated
    else
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Please log in"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. I'm going to give it a try and let you know.

Comment: One more update. I can't seem to figure out how to get the flash to persist to the sessions controller. I'm sure this should be another question, but wanted to document my results. The redirect worked though and that was the main challenge. Thanks!

Comment: I found away around the flash issue, just added a search param to the url and checked for it in the redirected controller. `redirect_url = (log_in_url.to_s + "?logged_out")` & then `render js: "window.location = #{redirect_url.to_json}"` Hacky I know, but works until I can find the "right way" to work it